# Translate regular expression to python

Tags: python, regex

I need to translate this regular expression to the python language:

```
(([[:alpha:]]|\.)*/PERSON([[:space:]]|$))+
```

I have a .txt file that contains names of people with the /PERSON tag and other words that do not have tags.

```
Leo/PERSON Messi/PERSON hello
```

Once you make the equivalent program in python to the regular expression above, the output must be this (all names with the label /PERSON, the other words are not):

```
Leo/PERSON Messi/PERSON
```

Comment: Can you include the code you have in Python in your question?

Comment: What's stopping you from doing the translation? I know this sounds like a trite comment, but your question shows no effort on your part. SO is not intended to be a free coding service where you can just post a request and people will do it for you. We need to you to make an attempt at it. Start by reviewing the Python docs for the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), which implements Python's regular expression engine. As is shown by other comments and answers on this question, *sometimes* people will be kind enough to do just that, but you shouldn't expect it.

Comment: `(?:[a-zA-Z.]*/PERSON(?:\s|$))+`? Took me 2 minutes. Check out https://regex101.com/

Comment: @JoshuaMolina from which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Regex pattern:

```
(?:[A-Za-z.]*/PERSON\s*)+
```

- `[A-Za-z.]*` matches zero or more of `[A-Za-z.]`
- `/PERSON\s*` matches `/PERSON` followed by zero or more whitespace
- The above is put in a non-captured group and the group is matched one or more time by the `+` token.

**Example:**

```
In [9]: re.search(r'(?:[A-Za-z.]*/PERSON\s*)+', 'Leo/PERSON Messi/PERSON hello').group()
Out[9]: 'Leo/PERSON Messi/PERSON '
```